# Intel DH77KC beeping only when adding the 3rd and 4th RAM

Tags: memory, ddr

I built a PC using a motherboard [Intel DH77KC](https://ark.intel.com/products/59506/Intel-Desktop-Board-DH77KC). I have at the moment 2x 4Go HyperX-DDR3-1600 (12800) and I want to install 2x generic HP 4Go DDR3-1600 (12800). When I insert the HP memory, the computer beeps 3 times at startup. The Intel motherboard beeping code website mention a RAM issue (I insert the HP ram in a HP PC and it boots without problems). So right now I only have 2 slots having 8Go DDR3 total but I want to have overall 16Go. My question is, since these 2 sets of RAM (different brand) are DDR3-1600/PC3-12800, why only 2 slots will work but as soon as I add the extra 8Go (HP Generic) it beeps and won't boot.

Is there a way to have two different kind of RAMs to work at the same time or the board doesn't support 4 channel?

Comment: What exactly is "4Go"?  Do you mean you want to install two generic 4 GB DDR3 modules?  Edit your question, and be precise, in what you are attempting to do.  Are these modules you are attempting to use ECC modules by chance?  Your question cannot be answered without more information.  Edit your question.

Comment: Are both manufacturers listed under the acceptable memory brands of the manual? Are you configuring the memory as the manual tells you to for your situation?

Comment: Edits done, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the added information however you still failed to answer my two questions. Please take a look at your motherboard manual and let me know what you find

Comment: The edit also failed to clarify what 4Go was exactly.  "Is there a way to have two different kind of rams to work at the same time or the board doesn't support 4 channel?" - Even if your motherboard supported 4 channel (it doesn't) the configuration you describe wouldn't be considered a quad channel configuration.  How do I know quad channel configuration is not possible, your motherboard does not have 8 memory slots, what you describe also wouldn't be considered a valid quad channel configuration.  Your motherboard only support dual channel configuration.

Comment: @Ramhound "Go" is Giga-Octet - an equivalent of Giga-byte. I've seen it used in (mainly) french countries, but some others as well. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gigaoctet

Comment: @Mokubai - I would understand if the author used GiB since that would be the scientific notation.  How am I suppose to identify a unit of measure memory that isn't used outside of France, French Canada and Romania?  I think my confusion is understandable.

Comment: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/motherboards/desktop/dh77kc/dh77kc_techprodspec04.pdf - This manual (page 19) mentions a difference in memory configurations based on double sided (DS) and single sided (SS) memory.  Check to see what you have, as that may be playing a part.  Normally if you go over the max RAM, it just doesn't recognize the "extra" RAM, but sometimes it gives RAM beeps.  Having an unsupported RAM config may also trigger the RAM beep code.